# Determine if an schedule is into a time range - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, time

I'm looking for a way to make an script that returns true if a value is into a time range. For example I have the next time range:

Monday to Friday since 8:00 to 11:00

If "now" is Monday at 15:00 returns false. But if "now" is Thuesday at 9:00 returns true.

How can I do it with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```js
// The date variable will be the date we
// want to check if it's in the time range
var date = new Date('08-30-2017 09:00:00');

// We define the start and the end of the 
// time range
var start = new Date('08-29-2017 09:00:00');
var end = new Date('08-31-2017 17:00:00');

// And create a Date type prototype function
// that will return if our date is inside that
// time range
Date.prototype.isInTimeRange = function(now, end) {
  // We run the getTime() method to convert the date
  // into integers
  return (this.getTime() >= start.getTime() && this.getTime() <= end.getTime());
}

// This should return true - the date
// is inside the time range
console.log(date.isInTimeRange(start, end));
```

And with a date that isn't on a time range:

```js
// The date variable will be the date we
// want to check if it's in the time range
var date = new Date('08-27-2017 09:00:00');

// We define the start and the end of the 
// time range and again
var start = new Date('08-29-2017 09:00:00');
var end = new Date('08-31-2017 17:00:00');

// And create a Date type prototype function
// that will return if our date is inside that
// time range
Date.prototype.isInTimeRange = function(now, end) {
  // We run the getTime() method to convert the date
  // into integers
  return (this.getTime() >= start.getTime() && this.getTime() <= end.getTime());
}

// This should return false - the date
// is not inside the time range
console.log(date.isInTimeRange(start, end));
```

Hope this helps you.